Querying in influxDB appears super slow. Isn't _field and _measurement "indexed"?
I run a simple query using a filter on the date column, plus _field and _measurement. The query runs nearly 10 minutes, which is super slow. Is there an automated index on these columns, or any way to speed this up?
Here the query:
from(bucket: "xyz")
|> range(start: 2024-09-01, stop: 2024-10-01)  
|> filter(
     fn: (r) => 
       r._field == "value" and 
       contains(value: r._measurement, set: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"])
   ) 

Thanks for any hint.

The range() function is naturally indexed, but there are a few key optimization opportunities:
For _field and _measurement filtering:

Think about the order of your filters - put the most restrictive ones first
Consider using =~ regex for multiple values instead of contains()
The _measurement column has a special indexing behavior you can leverage
Consider using aggregateWindow() for downsampling or limit()/offset() for pagination instead of manually chunking the time ranges.
Also consider using the EXPLAIN feature to analyze query performance

Here's a slightly optimized version of your query to try:
fluxCopyfrom(bucket: "xyz")
|> range(start: 2024-09-01, stop: 2024-10-01)  
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement =~ /^(aa|bb|cc|dd|ee)$/)


what do you intend with: "Try breaking up the time range into smaller chunks"?

Correction (updated answer), I meant If you need to handle large time ranges, consider using aggregateWindow() for downsampling or limit()/offset() for pagination instead of manually chunking the time ranges.
